# pandas: t-test and p-value of month over month mean difference in aggregated dataframe using groupby function

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first posted question, so please excuse if it doesn't look good.

I have a source data file which I transform to the following dataframe using pandas groupby aggregation

```
pd.read_csv('R:/Python ETL/AGG7.csv', sep=',')

      Treatment     Month   stdev    n    avg
0      AAAA       1/1/2016   1.92   309   7.57
1      AAAA       2/1/2016   1.89    79   7.46
2      AAAA       3/1/2016   2.25   158   7.20
3      AAAA       4/1/2016   2.23    22   7.68
4      BBBB       1/1/2016   2.04   175   7.10
5      BBBB       2/1/2016   1.96    33   7.09
6      BBBB       3/1/2016   2.02   110   7.32
7      BBBB       4/1/2016   1.73    25   7.92
8      CCCC       1/1/2016   2.42   111   7.40
9      CCCC       2/1/2016   1.45    22   7.73
10     CCCC       3/1/2016   2.44    21   6.95
11     CCCC       4/1/2016   2.84    92   6.92
```

What I need is 2 additional columns with month over month difference (MoM diff) and p-value of T-tests of those differences.

```
MoM diff    pValue
-0.11   0.35
-0.26   0.62
 0.48   0.65

-0.01   0.02
 0.23   0.44
 0.6    0.83

 0.33   0.46
-0.78   0.79
-0.03   0.04
```

The problem is that I cannot get them on the fly using pandas group by with scipy.stats ttest_ind function from original dataset and ttest_ind_from_stats function from the shown aggregated dataframe. I tried many different approaches, but with no success. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: how do you calculate `pValue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [df.shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with groupby to have the shifted values:

```
df[["avg_2", "n_2", "stdev_2"]] = df.groupby("Treatment")["avg", "n", "stdev"].shift()

df
Out[7]: 
   Treatment      Month  stdev    n   avg  avg_2    n_2  stdev_2
0       AAAA 2016-01-01   1.92  309  7.57    NaN    NaN      NaN
1       AAAA 2016-01-02   1.89   79  7.46   7.57  309.0     1.92
2       AAAA 2016-01-03   2.25  158  7.20   7.46   79.0     1.89
3       AAAA 2016-01-04   2.23   22  7.68   7.20  158.0     2.25
4       BBBB 2016-01-01   2.04  175  7.10    NaN    NaN      NaN
5       BBBB 2016-01-02   1.96   33  7.09   7.10  175.0     2.04
6       BBBB 2016-01-03   2.02  110  7.32   7.09   33.0     1.96
7       BBBB 2016-01-04   1.73   25  7.92   7.32  110.0     2.02
8       CCCC 2016-01-01   2.42  111  7.40    NaN    NaN      NaN
9       CCCC 2016-01-02   1.45   22  7.73   7.40  111.0     2.42
10      CCCC 2016-01-03   2.44   21  6.95   7.73   22.0     1.45
11      CCCC 2016-01-04   2.84   92  6.92   6.95   21.0     2.44
```

You can filter out `NaN` values with pd.notnull:

```
df2 = df[pd.notnull(df.avg_2)].copy()
```

And you can get the results of the t-tests with:

```
import scipy.stats as ss
res = ss.ttest_ind_from_stats(df2.avg, df2.stdev, df2.n, df2.avg_2, df2.stdev_2, df2.n_2, equal_var=False)
```

If you want the mean differences and p-values in this dataframe:

```
df2["dif_avg"] = df2.avg - df2.avg_2
df2["p_value"] = res.pvalue


Out[22]: 
        Month  stdev    n   avg  avg_2    n_2  stdev_2  dif_avg   p_value
1  2016-01-02   1.89   79  7.46   7.57  309.0     1.92    -0.11  0.646226
2  2016-01-03   2.25  158  7.20   7.46   79.0     1.89    -0.26  0.350814
3  2016-01-04   2.23   22  7.68   7.20  158.0     2.25     0.48  0.353023
5  2016-01-02   1.96   33  7.09   7.10  175.0     2.04    -0.01  0.978808
6  2016-01-03   2.02  110  7.32   7.09   33.0     1.96     0.23  0.559625
7  2016-01-04   1.73   25  7.92   7.32  110.0     2.02     0.60  0.137527
9  2016-01-02   1.45   22  7.73   7.40  111.0     2.42     0.33  0.395806
10 2016-01-03   2.44   21  6.95   7.73   22.0     1.45    -0.78  0.214270
11 2016-01-04   2.84   92  6.92   6.95   21.0     2.44    -0.03  0.961019
```

Line-by-line:

```
import csv
import scipy.stats as ss
results = []
treatment1 = ""
with open('R:/Python ETL/AGG7.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)
    for line in reader:
        treatment2, stdev2, n2, avg2 = line[0], float(line[2]), int(line[3]), float(line[4])
        if treatment2 == treatment1:
            ttest_res = ss.ttest_ind_from_stats(avg1, stdev1, n1, avg2, stdev2, n2, equal_var=False)
            results.append((avg2-avg1, ttest_res.pvalue))
        treatment1, stdev1, n1, avg1 = treatment2, stdev2, n2, avg2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very good solution. I just use df2=df.dropna()

Comment: I'm just curious if there is a way to calculate MoM_dif and pValue right from the source file, without aggregation like: df=DataSource.groupby(['Treatment','Month'])['Value_to_average'].agg({'avg':'mean','stdev':'std','n':'count'})   .- in one shot?

Comment: By reading line by line, you can use previous line's and current line's values to pass to the scipy's ttest if there is no change in the treatment. In the next line just update the values.

Comment: Could you please show me how this would look in a code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's very good! Thanks a lot! Do you think ttest_ind can be used without creating an aggregated file?

Answer (score 0):

is that what you need?

```
In [154]: df
Out[154]:
   Treatment     Month  stdev    n   avg
0       AAAA  1/1/2016   1.92  309  7.57
1       AAAA  2/1/2016   1.89   79  7.46
2       AAAA  3/1/2016   2.25  158  7.20
3       AAAA  4/1/2016   2.23   22  7.68
4       BBBB  1/1/2016   2.04  175  7.10
5       BBBB  2/1/2016   1.96   33  7.09
6       BBBB  3/1/2016   2.02  110  7.32
7       BBBB  4/1/2016   1.73   25  7.92
8       CCCC  1/1/2016   2.42  111  7.40
9       CCCC  2/1/2016   1.45   22  7.73
10      CCCC  3/1/2016   2.44   21  6.95
11      CCCC  4/1/2016   2.84   92  6.92

In [155]: df.stdev.diff()
Out[155]:
0      NaN
1    -0.03
2     0.36
3    -0.02
4    -0.19
5    -0.08
6     0.06
7    -0.29
8     0.69
9    -0.97
10    0.99
11    0.40
Name: stdev, dtype: float64
```

let's shift it one row up:

```
In [156]: df.stdev.diff().shift(-1)
Out[156]:
0    -0.03
1     0.36
2    -0.02
3    -0.19
4    -0.08
5     0.06
6    -0.29
7     0.69
8    -0.97
9     0.99
10    0.40
11     NaN
Name: stdev, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use your approach for another case when there is no difference in treatments.